# Angular CLI & Jenkins continous integration permissions

Tags: permissions, jenkins

I'm using jenkins for a continuous integration with angular cli, here are my steps :

- Push to github
- Jenkins pull the code from my github repository, do `npm install` and `ng build`

Everything is fine until here.

My problem is when I try to copy all the files build in `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/dist` to `/var/www/html/mywebsite`

This directory is managed by Nginx.

I've got this error : 
`cp: cannot create regular file '/var/www/html/mywebsite/./inline.bundle.js': Permission denied`

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use `sudo` when you copied data over?  Or, have you considered just symlinking the directory rather than copying data?

Comment: This also isn't an NGINX question but a system permissions question.  It only tangentially has to do with nginx in its current state.

Comment: I think it's not permitted to do `sudo` in jenkins `Execute Shell` section. I'll try with the symlink. Thanks

Comment: When I try sudo, I have this error : `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`

Comment: I had assumed you have access to the system *directly or via SSH*, rather than using Jenkins' shell as a go-between.  You can't create the symlink either without superuser privileges, so you may be out of luck with what you're trying to do, unless you have direct system access over SSH or such to make system-level revisions

Comment: Yes I've got access directly with SSH but I want that if I push on github, jenkins build and push automatically the new version

Comment: As you say, I create a symlink between my folders and it works! If you want, reply and I will set your answer as the good one! Thanks

Comment: Done, but with a few other cautionary suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't just *easily* copy the data over.  Rather, why not let NGINX go fetch the data via a symlink?

Create a symlink of the build destination directory in `/var/www` instead:

```
sudo mv /var/www/html /var/www/html.old
sudo ln -s /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/dist /var/www/html
```

This should, assuming that NGINX can also read the data in the `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mywebsite/dist` folder, bypass the need to let Jenkins directly copy things into a folder outside its control.

Note that I strongly suggest you use `/var/www/domain.tld`, replacing `domain.tld` with your actual site, and then use *that* for the document root in the `nginx` site configuration instead of `/var/www/html`.  There is an [NGINX Configuration Pitfalls entry about the potential issues of using the default document root which is relevant here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-the-default-document-root).  It specifically states:

> ### Using the Default Document Root
>
> NGINX packages that exist in Ubuntu, Debian, or other operating
> systems, as an easy-to-install package will often provide a ‘default’
> configuration file as an example of configuration methods, and will
> often include a document root to hold a basic HTML file.
>
> Most of these packaging systems do not check to see if files are
> modified or exist within the default document root, which can result
> in code loss when the packages are upgraded. Experienced system
> administrators know that there is no expectation of the data inside
> the default document root to remain untouched during upgrades.
>
> You should not use the default document root for any site-critical
> files. There is no expectation that the default document root will be
> left untouched by the system and there is an extremely high
> possibility that your site-critical data may be lost upon updates and
> upgrades to the NGINX packages for your operating system.